prompt llm to generate an email with well structured line breaks
I'm using the latest llms (mixtral/gemini/..)
I'm generating emails and I'm satisfied with the results except that the sentences are without proper line breaks.
The greeting and signature parts are ok but the main content is just sentences without line breaks.
I tried prompting:
insert new lines between sentences to format a well structured email

what else can I do?

Gemini has no issues writing paragraphs on my side. Example:


the email does look ok but for example 'Happy Birthday!' should have been in its own line.
I guess I can just add new lines with python thanks

I use following pyhton code to evaluates previous and current decoded tokens to detect new sentence and adds line break accordingly:
...
vNewDecoded = tokenizer_stream.decode(new_token)
if re.findall("^[\x2E\x3A\x3B]$", vPreviousDecoded) and vNewDecoded.startswith(" ") and (not vNewDecoded.startswith(" *")) :
    vNewDecoded = "\n" + vNewDecoded.replace(" ", "", 1)
print(vNewDecoded, end='', flush=True)
vPreviousDecoded = vNewDecoded
...

full code in:
onnx directml

The ideal prompt for this purpose will look some how like this :-
> You are an AI Assistant, and your task is to generate a proper email
> based on the user's query. Below is the user's query: Query: {query}
> Type: {type} You will return the helpful email. Helpful Answer:

But this will not only help you need to do some  formatting of the at code level for better result.
